# Ember guides todomvc tutorial

Tags: ember.js

I am following the tutorial in the Ember guides simply copy/pasting code. When I reach this part of the [tutorial](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/adding-a-route-and-template/) I get errors on reloading the page including:

> Failed to load resource file:///home/kwal0203/ember_development/ember_tutorial/js/libs/jquery.min.js
>   Failed to load resource file:///home/kwal0203/ember_development/ember_tutorial/js/libs/handlebars.js
>   Assertion failed: Ember Views require jQuery 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, or 2.0 ember.js:394
>   Assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars version 1.0.0. Include a SCRIPT tag in the HTML HEAD linking to the Handlebars file before you link to Ember. ember.js:394
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'COMPILER_REVISION' of undefined ember.js:23618
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined

Any help appreciated

Comment: can you post your code so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost clear why your app is not working, you are loading it using the `file://` protocol. This makes your vital js files to not load at all resulting in the errors you get.

```
Failed to load resource file:///home/kwal0203/ember_development/ember_tutorial/js/libs/jquery.min.js
...
```

The simple solution to your problem is to serve all the app related files from the `http://` protocol, this can be easy achieved using a simple webserver. If setting up a webserver is out of your scope then use a online editor like http://jsbin.com instead and load the js libraries from a CDN, then copy and paste all your code in the online editor and everything should work correctly.

If you have python installed on your system, another possibility to have your files served by a webserver could be the following:

```
$ cd /home/kwal0203/ember_development/ember_tutorial/
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Now open your browser and visit: `http://localhost:8000`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used my Python installation as above but now I get `404 errors`: 1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found) http://localhost:8000/js/libs/jquery.min.js
2.Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found) http://localhost:8000/js/libs/handlebars.js

Comment: I just renamed my .js files to match the errors and now it works haha thanks